# How to run subscriptions with apollo-server-express and neo4j?

Tags: javascript, websocket, neo4j, graphql, apollo-server

I was trying to run subscriptions on my server, but got an error

> "error": "Could not connect to websocket endpoint ws://localhost:3000/graphql. Please check if the endpoint url is correct."

My server.js is:

```
const { typeDefs } = require('./graphQLScheme');
const { createServer } = require("http");
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver');
const { Neo4jGraphQL, Neo4jGraphQLSubscriptionsSingleInstancePlugin } = require('@neo4j/graphql');
const { WebSocketServer } = require("ws");
const { useServer } = require("graphql-ws/lib/use/ws");
const express = require('express');
const  { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-express");
const { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer, ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground} = require("apollo-server-core");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const main = async () => {

  const driver = neo4j.driver(
    process.env.NEO4J_URI,
    neo4j.auth.basic(process.env.NEO4J_USER, process.env.NEO4J_PASSWORD)
  );

  const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({
    typeDefs,
    driver,
    plugins: {
      subscriptions: new Neo4jGraphQLSubscriptionsSingleInstancePlugin(),
    },
  });

  // apollo-server-express server setup with WebSockets
  const app = express();
  const httpServer = createServer(app);
  const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    server: httpServer,
    path: "/graphql",
  });

  // Neo4j schema
  const schema = await neoSchema.getSchema();
  const serverCleanup = useServer({
    schema
  }, wsServer);

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    playground: true,
    introspection: true,
    plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({
        httpServer
      }),
      ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground(),
      {
        async serverWillStart() {
          return {
            async drainServer() {
              await serverCleanup.dispose();
            },
          };
        },
      },
    ],
  });
  await server.start();
  server.applyMiddleware({
    app
  });

  const PORT = 3000;
  httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is now running on http://localhost:${PORT}/graphql`);
  });
}

main();
```

After start server I have GraphQL playground on http://localhost:3000/graphql, it also have subscriptions in docs and schema tabs, but when I'm trying to set subscription i get an error.

Comment: That server implementation looks roughly ok. I see that you are using GraphQL Playground, which seems to have limited support for graphql-ws subscriptions. Could you try the subscriptions with apollo studio to determine if it is a problem with the server or with the client? Remember to set the subscription implementation protocol to graphql-ws

Comment: @angrykoala, thank you, you saved my day) Really, it works fine with apollo studio.